# Is the tense-agreement in this question specific to "dare not", or are there other examples?

Tags: tense

> He knew she dare not tell her father.
>
> Kim daren’t tell them so I had to do it myself.
>
> -- The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p109n

My mother tongue, Korean, has tense inflectional options: to have tense agreement in a sentence or to put tense inflection only onto the last verb. The example cases remind me the Korean rule. So when I interpret English in my brain two or more past tenses in a sentence, I naturally ignore the other past tenses except one.

What I now want to know is that the pattern of the above cases be only restricted to ‘dare’, or are there more cases that in a sentence one verb is past, and the other present?

(I know in some cases, present perfect is replaced by simple tense for a kind of simplification.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *dare not* is a very dated construction - effectively a "set phrase" which is probably best avoided.

Precisely *because* it's unfamiliar/not current, I think many Anglophones would be ambivalent about whether it should be [knew she **dare** not](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22knew%20she%20dare%20not%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (7,060 hits in Google Books) or [knew she **dared** not](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22knew%20she%20dare%20not%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22knew%20she%20dared%20not%22&tbm=bks) (52,000 hits). Theoretically, I think the verb tense should depend on whether she *still* dares not, but I doubt many people would see it that way.

The modern "natural" phrasings would be...

> *He knew she **did not dare** [to] tell her father.*
>    *Kim **did not dare** [to] tell them so I had to do it myself.*

Personally, I don't think the tense forms in OP's examples are particularly relevant to modern usage.

Answer (score 3):

**SUPPLEMENTAL to FumbleFingers' answer:**
I am at a loss to conceive where CGEL finds warrant for past *dare*.

It is true that *dare* was **originally** a past form—but that was before even Old English.

It is true that *OED 1* records a couple of “careless” uses of *dare* for past tense in the 19th century--probably attributable to the flux in which *dare* then found itself, for it is also true that the old strong past form *durst* started to disappear in the 16th century, and that 3sg *dare* started to decline about the same time.

But what replaced *dare* 3sg and *durst* pa were *dares* and *dared*.

There used to be a dialectal negative *dassent* (you'll find it all over Mark Twain). This was pretty heavily stomped upon by the schoolmarms, which may have contributed to the general decline of modal-form *dare* over the past two hundred years.

In any case, I concur in FumbleFingers' judgment. Use *dares* in 3sg, *dared* in past positive, and *do/does/did not dare* in the negative. All the others are on life-support; let 'em flatline.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 special verbs in English- dare and need. Both can be used as modal and non-modal verbs.

Modal verb---He dare not say that, He need not say that.

Non-modal verb---He didn't (or doesn't) dare to say that, He didn't (or doesn't) need to say that.